# PayPal: Express Checkout. Set up a one-time payment and recurring payment in single transaction

Tags: c#, paypal, express-checkout

I'm using PayPal Express Checkout and I'm trying to set up a one time payment and a recurring payment, all in the same transaction.

According to Paypal, this is possible calling DoExpressCheckout before creating the recurring profile (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/) , but I'm having trouble with the SetExpressCheckout call.

If I call SetExpressCheckout with the one-time payment info, in the review page the info of the recurring payment won't be displayed. 
If I call SetExpressCheckout with the recurring payment info, in the review page the info of the one-time payment won't be displayed. 
If I call SetExpressCheckout with the both payments (one-time & recurring), it will throw an error saying "Billing Agreement is not supported for parallel payments"

Can anyone help with some ideas of how to set up the PayPal calls in the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetExpressCheckout should be called with the one-time payment info, but with the billing agreement fields setup for recurring payments.  Then you would also call DoExpressCheckoutPayment with the one-time payment info, and then follow that up with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, and that's where you would specify the recurring payment details.

Comment: But in that case, in the PayPal review only the details of the one-time payment will be shown? or both the one-time payment info and the recurring payment info? In my case, the one-time payment amount is different from the recurring payment amount.

Comment: It would only break down the cart items, but it would provide info about a billing agreement being setup and the button they push would say "Agree and Continue" instead of just "Continue".  So then it's up to you within your application to display the details about the subscription to the buyer before they go to PayPal and after they're back.

Comment: Again, that doesn't get setup until after you call DoExpressCheckoutPayment, so you could display a thank you page and within that provide a break down of the subscription and another button to finalize, or just do the calls together and thank them for everything at once.

Comment: Thank you Andrew!! I was able to do both transactions in a single call using your advice!

Comment: Glad I could help out!